# django model instance variables for transient use

Tags: python, django

I would like to create some instance variables for my model subclass, but when saving the object to the database I don't want a table column for that variable.  I read in some places you would do this by overriding **init**() like how you would create normal instance variables in other classes.  Is this the accepted way for subclasses of model?  Are there other approaches?

models.py:

```
class MyModel (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.tempvar = ''
```

views.py:

```
myModel = MyModel()
myModel.tempvar = 'this will not be saved in the database'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an acceptable way of doing it, although you don't need to initialize it unless there's a chance you may try to access it when it doesn't exist. Also, consider if you should be using a property instead.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Python 3: You can call `super()` directly without repeating the class name

```py
class MyModel (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.tempvar = ''
```